# how to open the database by using a hidden form with startup routin?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to improve the performance of my MS Access database that has a Linked tables.
I read this microsoft support [artikel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889588) and it was so wonderful but I could not understand somthings:

how can I create a Form thast is base on a table?

I should to open database by using a hidden form with startup routin. would you please explain me these solution step by step.I'm very new in MS Access and VB

Comment: Using a form with a start-up routine does not improve performance, it is actually there to show the user that something is happening, e.g a fake loading screen will distract the user while the database loads (thus not giving the same impression of slowness)

Comment: If you have not got as far as creating a form based on a table, you have quite a bit to go before worrying about hidden start up forms. I recommend you look for tutorials and start there.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a form, change the Record Source property to a table in the database.  I usually use a dummy table for the start up form.  My dummy table has one field and no data in it, but that's enough to improve the performance.

While developing, I just keep the dummy table open all the time so I don't have to worry about closing any other forms.